javascript program stops executing
I have a Package Class where a random ID is given at the beginning and a package type can be chosen afterwards.
It seems, that the values are given correctly. I can click between package and letter.But when the method chooseType has been called the second time, the program stops executing, after the method returned the value. The console is not logging the "typeOfPackage". Any suggestions would be appreciated.


//Generate PackageId 
let generateID = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)

}

// choose type of element to be sent
var e = document.getElementById("selectPackageType");
let chooseType = () => {
  var value = e.value;
  return value;
}

const randomID = generateID();
console.log(randomID);

e.onchange = chooseType;
const typeOfPackage = chooseType();

if (typeOfPackage == null) {
  console.log("type of packege is null")
} else {
  console.log(typeOfPackage);
}
<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="selectPackageType">Type:</label>
  <select id="selectPackageType">
    <option value="1">letter</option>
    <option value="2">package</option>
  </select>
</form>




Everything from const typeOfPackage = chooseType(); is only executed ONE time, when the script was first executed, regardless of what you choose in your elements. A possible solution might be to put that code inside the chooseType function.

thank you. I put the code into the choseType function and it works fine.

As I explained in a comment to the question, the bug is that everything from const typeOfPackage = selectType() is only executed ONCE, when the script is run for the first time, regardless of what you choose in your elements.

I will here provide a few more points that I hope you will find helpful.
let generateID = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)
}

I don't understand why you use an arrow function to declare generateID . If you really want to declare the function this way, my recommendation is to do it with const, no curly brackets nor return:
const generateID = () => Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);

But I prefer a normal function:
function generateID() {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
} 

Next is your chooseType function, which is called as an event handler when the element has changed. First, I renamed it "updatedType" and declared it as a normal function instead of an arrow function. This makes this a reference to the element that called the function, making it possible to use the same function to several different elements. I also moved the code that prints the value into this function, so that piece of code is executed when the element is changed. Since it's an event handler called by the element, there's no need to return a value, so I removed the return statement.
function updatedType() {
  var value = this.value;
  if (value == null) {
    console.log('type of packege is null');
  } else {
    console.log(value);
  }
}

There are several ways to add an event handler to an element. The onchange you used is one of them and works just fine in small projects. The main disadvantage of that method is that it is only possible to have one event handler attached to the element. It's not a problem in small projects, but in larger projects you may want to have more than one event handler on the same element, and for that there is addEventListener.
document.getElementById('selectPackageType').addEventListener('change', updatedType);

Worth noting is that if there is no element with id "selectPackageType" the code will stop executing with an error message. In larger projects, you hopefully use some library that handles it for you and minimizes what you need to write.
I hope you find my comments helpful and I wish you the best of luck in your future programming adventures.

chooseType doesn't actually do very much, so even though it's getting invoked every time you change the dropdown, there are no observable side effects to help you see that that's the case. You can either change chooseType itself to do all the things you want to have done, or use a different function as your callback.


//Generate PackageId 
let generateID = () => {
  return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2)

}

// choose type of element to be sent
var e = document.getElementById("selectPackageType");
let chooseType = () => {
  var value = e.value;
  return value;
}

const randomID = generateID();
console.log(randomID);
const updateType = () => {
    const typeOfPackage = chooseType();

    if (typeOfPackage == null) {
      console.log("type of packege is null")
    } else {
      console.log(typeOfPackage);
    }
}
// set things up based on the initial selection
updateType();
// set things up again any time the selection changes
e.onchange = updateType;
<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="selectPackageType">Type:</label>
  <select id="selectPackageType">
    <option value="1">letter</option>
    <option value="2">package</option>
  </select>
</form>




 //Generate PackageId
      let generateID = () => {
        return Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
      };

      // choose type of element to be sent
      var e = document.getElementById("selectPackageType");
      let chooseType = () => {
        var value = e.value;
        const randomID = generateID();
        console.log(randomID);

        const typeOfPackage = value; // can be remove this extra variable by using value direct itself

        if (typeOfPackage == null) {
          console.log("type of packege is null");
        } else {
          console.log(typeOfPackage);
        }
        return value;
      };

      e.onchange = chooseType;`enter code here`


As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Yes, @StriplingWarrior fixed the important issues. But the whole thing can be done in three (now: five!) lines:


const randomId=Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
let   typeOfPackage;
document.getElementById("selectPackageType").onchange=ev=>
  console.log(typeOfPackage=ev.target.value);
console.log(randomId);
<form autocomplete="off">
  <label for="selectPackageType">Type:</label>
  <select id="selectPackageType">
    <option value="1">letter</option>
    <option value="2">package</option>
  </select>
</form>



In this updated version I removed the conditional consol.log() message "type of packege is null", as it would never have been shown anyway. The ev.target.value in the onchange event handler will always return a string. In case of an empty option being chosen that would be an empty string ("") but never a null.

Yes, the code in the question can be written much shorter, but you have changed what the code does, because you do not save the value of the generated id. The code posted in the question is not the complete code, but the asker has followed the guidelines and posted a minimal example of the part of the code they were having trouble with.

Ok, point taken . To remedy that I added two more lines with adequate declarations and the job is done.
